# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\policycode\sample_code\policy1.php on line 54

Tags: php

Below is the program i have created using PHP.

```
foreach (.$resource->getAttributeMap()->entrySet() as .$entry);
if($entrey->getkey()->equal($Resource->RESOURCE_ID_KEY))
    continue;
echo".$entry->getkey(). $entry->getValue()[0]";
```

The program can't iterator for each. How to the solve the issue?

Comment: please paste the previous lines of code, the error will be there

Comment: and whats that `.` at the start of the foreach? that looks wrong

Comment: check line number 53 code. possible missing `;` and also remove `.` in foreach loop

Comment: `foreach ($resource->getAttributeMap()->entrySet() as $entry);` the `;` ends your loop it's like doing `foreach ($resource->getAttributeMap()->entrySet() as $entry){}`  Based on how bad this one snip-it is, I hazard to say there are many many errors.  (don't take that personally, i'm just making an observation, we all have to start somewhere)

Answer (score 0):

The actual context of the code is not clear but it has syntax errors like .(dot) preceding the variable names, not consistent variable names etc. A modified code would be :

```
foreach ($resource->getAttributeMap()->entrySet() as $entry){
    if($entry->getkey()->equal($resource->RESOURCE_ID_KEY)){
       continue;
    }
    echo $entry->getkey()."". $entry->getValue()[0];
 }
```